# Ambassador Mapping Rewrite Needs Original URL In Header

Tags: http-headers, envoyproxy, ambassador

I'm using Ambassador Mappings created through a Helm chart in order to rewrite and forward a web request. The client has requested that we include the originally requested URL in a header when we forward the request.

Based on documentation, it looks like there are only two dynamic values I can set: %DOWNSTREAM_REMOTE_ADDRESS_WITHOUT_PORT% and %PROTOCOL%, neither of which seems to solve my issue.

Are there any ways for me to set this header properly through an Ambassador mapping?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So I think we've found the solution. If you use Envoy's syntax and make sure that is forwarded through, you can use their REQ() function, to get the authority and path, to construct the URL. For example:

`http://%REQ(:authority)%%REQ(:path)%`

Here is the documentation for all of the possibilities you can use with Envoy through Ambassador's mapping: https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_conn_man/headers#custom-request-response-headers